A formula to find both text in asterisks and find text next to parentheses
Looking for a way to potentially combine my formulas and haven't had any success. I look at large, variable sheets where I only want to review the Active Description, but the data that I'm given lists the Active Description with all of the previous iterations (Inactive Description). Unfortunately, it lists the Active Description in multiple formats.
Currently I am doing the following to get a column that only has the Active Descriptions:
To only show text in asterisks:
=MID(B2,FIND("*",B2)+1,FIND("*",B2,FIND("*",B2)+1)-FIND("*",B2)-1)

To only show the Active Description when the description has the active next to a (type):
Text to columns with line break as a delimiter, then combining the results with the Active Description into one source column (issue is that it the number of line breaks can be highly variable). To only show the text that isn't in parentheses:
=TRIM( TEXTBEFORE(B1,"("))

And finally for the descriptions that only have active in the column, I'm copying them over as is.
Is there one if statement that I can write to do it all at once?

Is there a reason you cannot use something like=IF(FIND("Active Description",B2)>=1,"Active Description","")?

The active description is variable in length and content. So one might be (for example - nonsense data) "Loraine Ewing's pocketwatch" and the next would be "A cup, pair of socks, and banana belonging to Nestor Palmer".

I assume Active Description and Inactive Description are place holders. But in your data, how can you tell if a Description is Inactive and should be ignored?

There is (unfortunately) nothing that indicates that a description is inactive. In our database they don't get rid of the inactive descriptions, they just add the updated one as a new line. The active descriptions are denoted by either being in asterisks or by having a word in parentheses next to them.

@user25082756 but your Option3 shows a desired output of Active Description, even though it is neither in asterisks nor followed by a parentheses.

Yes, it can have an active description that is current with nothing inactive. I was hoping to write a formula to include those too, but they can stay in the original column as well. I'll edit my post to upload a better picture example!

Would the active description always be on the last line? Do you absolutely need to get rid of the * and parenthesis?

@cybernetic.nomad Active description is always on the last line, yes! I don't need to get rid of the * and () though.

I uploaded a more accurate picture of what the issue is

If you don't need to get rid of the asterisks or (type): =LET(t,TEXTAFTER(B2,CHAR(10),-1),IF(OR(RIGHT(t)={")","*"}),t,""))

Lovely question, though better to post data as data (markdown table) rather than images of your data.

This worked! @P.b noted for the future. Thanks!

=LET(a,{"*";"(type)"},
     b,TEXTSPLIT(B5,CHAR(10)),
TEXTSPLIT(TOCOL(IFS(FIND(a,b),b),2),a,,1))

First a is declared: an array of the asterisk sign and (type).
Next b is declared: an array of the cell value split by end of line character CHAR(10).
If we find a in b it errors on strings not containing any of the a strings.
If the string does contain any of the two, it returns that string including the a string(s) found in it.
If we split that by a and tell TEXTSPLIT to ignore empty strings, the a string(s) contained will be deleted (splitter out). Resulting in your Active string.
Or in one spill:
=MAP(B2:B5,LAMBDA(m,LET(a,{"*";"(type)"},b,TEXTSPLIT(m,CHAR(10)),TEXTSPLIT(TOCOL(IFS(FIND(a,b),b),2),a,,1))))
Including error handling for no string meeting the conditions and comma separated in case multiple returns per cell:
=MAP(B2:B5,LAMBDA(m,LET(a,{"*";"(type)"},b,TEXTSPLIT(m,CHAR(10)),ARRAYTOTEXT(IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TOCOL(IFS(FIND(a,b),b),2),a,,1),"")))))

=MAP(B2:B5,LAMBDA(m,LET(b,TEXTSPLIT(m,CHAR(10)),IFERROR(@TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TOCOL(IFS(SEARCH({"~*";"(*)"},b),b),2),{"(","*"},,1)),"")))) with adjustments made to original post

With XLOOKUP:
=LAMBDA(data,
    BYROW(
        data,
        LAMBDA(row,
            LET(
                newline, CHAR(10),
                lines, TEXTSPLIT(row, , newline),
                IF(
                    ROWS(lines) = 1,
                    lines,
                    LET(
                        in_asterisks, SUBSTITUTE(
                            XLOOKUP("~**~*", lines, lines, , 2),
                            "*",
                            ""
                        ),
                        next_to_parens, TEXTBEFORE(
                            XLOOKUP("?*(*)", lines, lines, , 2),
                            "("
                        ),
                        TRIM(IFNA(in_asterisks, IFNA(next_to_parens, row)))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)(A2:A7)


